# when i am refreshing the page i getting blank page?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt

in this express js code i handled a login request but i am refreshing the page the profile goes disappeared and it shows blanck page and i think token is expired when i am refreshing the page
i also added logout function in front end react code which will remove the token from the local storage

````
const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body

        // check if user exists
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!user) {
            return res.json({
                error: 'No user found'
            })
        }
        // check if password match
        const match = await comparePassword(password, user.password)
        if (match) {
            jwt.sign({ id: user._id, email: user.email, phone: user.phone, name: user.name, picture: user.picture }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1h' }, (err, token) => {
                res.cookie('token', token).json(user);
            });
        }
        if (!match) {
            res.json({
                error: 'Passwords do not match'
            })
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: 'Internal server Error',
        })
    }
}

const getProfile = (req, res) => {
    const { token } = req.cookies;
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {}, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                // Handle token expiration or verification failure here
                res.clearCookie('token'); // Clear the expired token
                res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
            } else {
                res.json(user);
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.json(null);
    }
};```


i am expecting the the data on front should be there when i refresh the page
````